# Java unable to open pdf using Runtime

Tags: java, actionlistener, netbeans-7, runtime.exec, jsr296

I have to open a pdf on clicking a JMenuItem. I can open the pdf on click the menu item if i run my program from netbeans. But when i run from jar file it is not opening. I clean and build my project. But no change. Running when run from netbeans but not running from jar file.
Do i need to add some library.

My codes are as follows

```
m_aboutItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
           //System.out.println(Menubar1.getDefaultLocale());
                URL link2=Menubar1.class.getResource("/newpkg/Documentation.pdf");
                String link=link2.toString();
                link=link.substring(6);
                System.out.println(link);
                System.out.println(link2);
                String link3="F:/new/build/classes/newpkg/Documentation.pdf";
                try {
                Process proc = rt.exec("rundll32.exe url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + link2);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Menubar1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    });
```

Tried this as well but getting same thing.. i can open pdf from menuitem when i run from netbeans but not from jar application.

```
m_aboutItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
            Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
            URL link2=Menubar1.class.getResource("/newpkg/Documentation.pdf");
                String link=link2.toString();
                link=link.substring(6);
                System.out.println(link); 
            File file=new File(link);
            System.out.println(file);
                try {
                    desktop.open(file);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Menubar1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }

        }
    });
```

The output for all the system.out.println() is as follows when run from netbeans for this second code

```
run:
```

F:/new/build/classes/newpkg/Documentation.pdf
F:\new\build\classes\newpkg\Documentation.pdf
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 5 seconds)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rundll32.exe` can not deal with a resource that is now inside a Jar.  Inspect the URL returned by `getResource(String)`.

> ..but still not working..

The problem is that `rundll32` was, for PDFs at least, only for `File` instances.  The tools that consume (e.g. display) PDFs are generally not designed to accept command line args. representing an `URL`.  If the `URL` should turn out to point to a `File`, the process can proceed.  But once the PDF is in a Jar, it is just an entry in a Jar.  Or to put that another way, it is **not a `File`.**

If that reasoning is correct, one way to get the PDF displayed in the default software is to:

1. Get the `URL` to the PDF as done now.
2. Check if the `URL` points to a Jar (it will contain a '!'). If it does..

   1. **Extract the PDF from the Jar to a (temporary) `File` on disk.**
3. Display the (perhaps temporary) `File`.

Comment: Thanks ! Yes this works,but we need to distribute this software, therefore we cannot hardcode the file path.
I tried the following but still not working
String link=link2.toString();
Sopln(link) was: file:/F:/new/classes/build/newpkg/Documentation.pdf
So i extracted the path only by link=link.substring(6);
Sopnl(link) now is: F:/new/classes/build/newpkg/Documentation.pdf
if i write getResource(link) again same thing is happening.
If i directly write link="F:/new/classes/build/newpkg/Documentation.pdf";. It works as you said in both netbeans and jar.
Is there any way to make path un-hardcoded

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying so fast.

And i tried to print the variable link2.
The output was: file:/F:/new/build/classes/newpkg/Documentation.pdf only
Sry i interchanged build and classes in the above comment.

Okay... can you give few more details how to do that.. i mean any url or tutorial i can go through for that...

Comment: *"The output was: `file:/F:/new/build/classes/newpkg/Documentation.pdf` only"*  Are you sure that is the output when you 'run from Jar file' - I.E. when it *fails?*  I am surprised you pasted that URL, since it contains no **`!`** and should work (according to my best theories).

Comment: I am surprised as well.
Look at the code... i edited it.. Printing both link2 and link
Output in netbeans window is
run:<break>
F:/new/build/classes/newpkg/Documentation.pdf<break>
file:/F:/new/build/classes/newpkg/Documentation.pdf
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 8 seconds)

When i uses link3 in exec command... everything is working..While link3 is same as link.

<break> is just to make symbolic representation of change of line

Comment: Two days before it was working with link2 only. I changed few codes but havent changed anything in that menu... it stops working now.. i dont have any idea why.. i thought... may be i need to bind few libraries

Comment: And i just copied pasted the output "Sopln's" from the output window of the netbeans..so this is it..

Comment: *"from the output window of the netbeans.."*  Will you leave your *bl00dy* IDE out of it for a minute?  I am not interested in the output where it works in the IDE, **but the output where it breaks.**

Answer (score 1):

Can you use Java 6 and the [`Desktop`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html) API?

and on startup can you export or download the file to disk?

Comment: Not for a resource in a Jar file.  `Desktop.open(File)/.edit(File)` methods each expect a `File`.  Resources in Jars are only available by `URL`.  (And `Desktop.browse(URI)` passes the URI to a browser, which is equally unlikely to be able to load resources from archives.)

Comment: Tried this too.. This is also working but from netbeans not from jar..

i edited and added the codes for this as all... here also i tried Sopln() for assistance.. all are written above..

I dont know what to do now.. and yes i clean and build my project before opening the jar file and open the correct jar file only..

Answer (score 0):

```
 try                                      //try statement
     {
         Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + "c:\\chart.pdf");   //open the file chart.pdf

     } catch (Exception e)                    //catch any exceptions here
       {
           System.out.println("Error" + e );  //print the error
       }
```

Comment: *"it works for me"*  Luck must be on your side, perhaps you should buy a lottery ticket.  Please review [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html) & incorporate the advice into your (code &) future answers.

Comment: Thanks it works but path is quite hard-coded.. i dont want to hard core.. as the software is for distribution... please check my question once again as i edited.. n reply..